# Extract icons from files takes too long

Tags: java, icons

I need to display lots of files with filename and icon in my program.
Therefor I am extracting the icons from the files, but it takes too long.

I have tried 2 different methods to extract the icons, but both are really slow (in my case REALLY slow, because I get the files from a networkdrive).

Here is an example, where I extract the icons and count the number of icons (do nothing with the files/icons)

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    File folder = new File("C:\\Windows\\System32\\");
    File[] list = folder.listFiles();

    for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++) {
      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      System.out.println("Method 1: " + getIconNumber1(list)+ " Icons");
      long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
      System.out.println("Finished Method 1 in " + (float) elapsedTime / 1000 + "sec");

      long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
      System.out.println("Method 2: " + getIconNumber2(list)+ " Icons");
     long stopTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
      long elapsedTime2 = stopTime2 - startTime2;
      System.out.println("Finished Method 2 in " + (float) elapsedTime2 / 1000 + "sec");
      System.out.println("-----------------");
    }
  }

  private static int getIconNumber1(File[] list) {
    int nr = 0;
    for(File f : list) {
      try {
        ShellFolder sf = ShellFolder.getShellFolder(f);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(sf.getIcon(true));
        nr++;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    return nr;
  }

  private static int getIconNumber2(File[] list) {
    int nr = 0;

    for(File f : list){
      FileSystemView view = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
      Icon icon =  view.getSystemIcon(f);
      nr++;
    }
    return nr;
  }
}
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: For a folder like System32 I'd assume there to be: #1: A boatload of files #2: Lots of files sharing the same icon. So if checking the file type is cheaper than getting the icon (I assume it is) then you could check if you already had processed this type of file and skip to the next one.

Comment: If that doesn't help much, you could lighten the weight of the task by splitting up the array in half (or more) and assign both halfs to separate threads which will process them individually.

Comment: You want to display filenames and icons. Would displaying them in a JList be an option for you?

Comment: @Ceiling Thanks for your answer! On my program I dont loop through sys32, I extract icons from a networkdrive. All those files are shortcuts (so ending is .lnk). I will give multithreading a try, but I already have 3 threads running, which all parse different filesets.